# positioning html e-mail signatures

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

Hey so I'm having a bit of trouble getting the positioning right of my text when I try to upload my html e-mail signatures in outlook.  When I go to pull my signatures up in my browser it looks completely fine (I've tested safari, chrome and firefox).  However once I upload the signatures the text is moved down significantly.  I'm not sure what the problem is but if anyone has any ideas I'd really appreciate it.  Heres my code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Code Morris</title>


    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
    @font-face 
    {
    font-family: 'montserrat-regular';
    src: url('http://www.codemorris.com/montserrat-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('http://www.codemorris.com/montserrat-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix')     format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('http://www.codemorris.com/montserrat-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('http://www.codemorris.com/montserrat-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('http://www.codemorris.com/montserrat-regular-webfont.svg#montserrat-regular-webfont') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

    }
    a 
    { 
        text-decoration: none; 
        color:black

    }

    .logo 
    {
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    }
    #p1
    {
    position:fixed;
    font-family: 'montserrat-regular';
    font-size:160%;
    top: 40px;
    margin-left: 300px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    }

    #p2
    {
    position:fixed;
    font-family: 'montserrat-regular';
    font-size:125%;
    margin-top: 65px;
    margin-left: 300px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    }
    #p3
    {
    position:fixed;
    font-family: 'montserrat-regular';
    font-size:97%;
    top: 120px;
    margin-left: 300px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    }
    #p4
    {
    position:fixed;
    font-family: 'montserrat-regular';
    font-size:97%;
    top: 144px;
    margin-left: 300px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    }
    #p5
    {
    position:fixed;
    font-family: 'montserrat-regular';
    font-size:97%;
    top: 170px;
    margin-left: 300px;
    white-space: nowrap;


    }
    #p6
    {
    position:fixed;
    font-family: 'montserrat-regular';
    font-size:97%;
    top: 210px;
    margin-left: 300px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    }
    #p7
    {
    position:fixed;
    font-family: 'montserrat-regular';
    font-size:97%;
    top: 235px;
    margin-left: 300px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    }
    #p8
    {
    position:fixed;
    font-family: 'montserrat-regular';
    font-size:97%;
    top: 258px;
    margin-left: 300px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    }






-->  

</style>


</head>
<body>

<div class="logo">
<a href="http://www.codemorris.com/" target="_blank"><img      src="http://www.codemorris.com/CMO_logo.jpg" width="265" height="265"> </a>
</div>

<div id="p1">
ANDY MORRIS
</div>

<div id="p2">
CEO
</div>

<div id="p3">
@andymorris
</div>

<div id="p4">
<a href="mailto:andy.morris@codemorris.com"> andy.morris@codemorris.com </a>
</div>

<div id="p5">
917.710.1802
</div>

<div id="p6">
<a href="www.codemorris.com"> www.codemorris.com </a>
</div>

<div id="p7">
85 Delancey Street, Penthouse
</div>

<div id="p8">
New York, NY 10002
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `once I upload the signatures` What do you mean by that?

Comment: When I add my html code into the signature section in outlook